# Select all/bulk messages

Tags: telegram

Is there a way or a script to select all/bulk messages in a channel/chat to be then forwarded?
The chat has like 4000 messages going back to 2019 so it's not feasable to do it manually
I've found this script online but it doesn't work, i'm not really into coding tbf, I just copy and paste.

http://shreekantranade.blogspot.com/2020/09/selecting-all-messages-from-telegram.html

````
function sel(cnt=200){$($(".im_history_selected_wrap .im_history_messages .im_history_messages_peer:not(.ng-hide) .im_message_outer_wrap").get().reverse()).each(function(e, el){if (e>cnt) return; el.click(); }); }

// bring all messages into view
lst=document.getElementsByClassName("im_history_scrollable_wrap");
ele=lst[0]
//ele.scrollTo(0,-100); // test
function scrl() { ele.scrollTo(0,-10000); }
var loop1 = setInterval(scrl, 1);

////clearInterval(loop1); //stop the loop once reached the top```
````